# PChart - Y Axis does not start from 0

Tags: php, pchart

I generate stacked bar chart using PChart, but Y Axis does not start from 0.
Is there manual parameter that I should set? Here the chart

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$graph->drawScale(array("Mode" => SCALE_MODE_START0));
```

This works for standard bar charts, I assume it would work for stacked. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a couple of ways to solve this issue.  According to the [documentation](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.scale.html) you should be able to use:

```
$graph->drawScale(array("Mode"=> SCALE_MODE_ADDALL_START0));
```

however, when I was generating stacked charts, it kept adding an additional mark at 110%, to solve this I decided to use:

```
$scaleProperties = array(0=>("Min"=>0, "Max"=>100));
$graph->drawScale(array("Mode" => SCALE_MODE_MANUAL, "ManualScale"=>$scaleProperties));
```

You would simply change the `"Max"` value to whatever your top end is, this forces the scale to stay between 0 and the maximum value.